# ASP.NET host not applying most recent code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

So I'm working on a web app that I'm making frequent code changes to.  Starting earlier today I realized that changes I made, both in the .aspx pages and the codebehind weren't being served up.  I looked in the files on the server and they're current but when I surf the page I'm getting behavior from the previous version.  Haven't seen this before and I'm befuddled as to what to do... I tried both publishing the changes directly from VS as well as FTP'ing the files myself, no difference.

Comment: Does clearing browser's cache help?

Comment: check all your assumptions

Comment: I'm with Matt, check all your assumptions.  E.g. check IIS logs to make sure you are actually hitting the site you think you are hitting.

Comment: Figured it out... the code change affected database updates and the datagrid shows only the most recent.  When I tested it locally, it wrote updates in my local time vs the updates I made when it was deployed which were server time :| So it kept showing my "older" updates.

Needless to say when I looked at the database there was a "doh" moment...

Comment: P.S ... I know it doesn't explain my aspx change not happening but I'm too relieved to contemplate what that was about.